# Use selenium to log in chrome with different user

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

Now I want to do automated web testing with selenium in Specflow, and I have several credentials to test. The question is How to switch domain to log in chrome browser with C# code in selenium. I have tried the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282540/selenium-web-driver-running-as-different-user-not-getting-profile-session-of-use) But I found the new chromedriver() cannot be modifiied. I can do manually change the domain by shift and right click chrome browser to run as a different user, but I can't solve it automaticaly.