# Run chromedriver as different domain user than the logged in profile

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know if there's a way to launch a chromedriver instance as a different domain user than the one logged in. I saw that there is a command line switch for specific chrome user profiles but I didn't see one in my searching for a domain profile.

To be more specific I'm looking to implement a selenium/chromedriver equivalent to this command in java:
    `runas /user:domain\username chrome <pathToChrome>`

Thanks in advance,
Dylan

Comment: Are you talking about impersonation? If yes, Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282540/selenium-web-driver-running-as-different-user-not-getting-profile-session-of-use) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590207/how-to-impersonate-a-specific-user-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: That is what I'm referring to but those implementations are in C# and are over my head. I was unable to find one in java.