# Selenium IE open as different user

Tags: python, selenium

Hi i want to use selenium to open Internet Explorer-11 as different user. I have done a search and it show that it is possible but with Java, I am using Python so I am wondering is it possible with Internet Explorer webdriver or not.

For example if you right click on internet explorer, it will have the part sign in as different user. I want to automate that part with python IE webdriver, but I do not know how to do it.

what I am asking is similar to this post [How to impersonate a specific user with Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590207/how-to-impersonate-a-specific-user-with-selenium-webdriver) 
but I want to do it in Python with selenium webdriver

To be clear. I know how to open the webrowser with selenium and i know how to sign in with selenium (when there is a pop up window). But I am asking about how to let selenium know that I want to sign in as different user. Because if I just open my browswer normally there is no pop up for sign in.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Ie()
```

[image: this is the desktop that is opened by selenium- there is no pop up for sign in]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please share your source code, even if its the Java version, it might help to follow the same approach in Python.

Comment: No I have not tried anything. Because I do not know how to do that in Python I can only open my internet explorer under my current username, and I am not doing it in Java. And I do not know whether it is possible to do that in Python or not. My project start by singing in to IE with different user, and now I am stuck in the very first step. So I am so sorry but I am currently got no code to share

Comment: What kind of different user you mean? OS or application?

Comment: what does "open IE11 as different user" actually mean?

Comment: @ Dalton well in the application only. For example if you right click on internet explorer, it will have the part sign in as different user. I want to automate that part with python IE webdriver, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: That should be explained in your question, it is unclear what you are asking. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)

Comment: when I right click on internet explorer I don't see anywhere an option such as "sign in as different user", what do you mean exactly? When you click on the IE icon on windows or inside a Web page? In that image you posted you are not redirecting to any page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium Web Driver](http://www.techbeamers.com/selenium-webdriver-python-tutorial/).

Learning about it you can do what you need with a code similar to this:

```
username = selenium.find_element_by_id("username")
password = selenium.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("yourPa55worD")

selenium.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

Since it seems you want to use another OS user, I suggest you use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/):

> Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

I think there is no way to do what you are wanting with just Selenium. If you need to integrate Selenium and Sikuli, you can see this post on SOF: [Calling to a Sikuli script from Python (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198121/calling-to-a-sikuli-script-from-python-selenium/20366782#20366782) . It can give some ideas for you.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for  your help. But when i open internet explorer, there is no pop up for sign in. I have to first to right click the internet explorer, chose run as different user, then the pop up will appear. What I am asking is how I can automate that task with selenium.

Comment: So, it is not an application user as you told before. It seems it is a different OS user, since you will start a process in OS (IE), not a session of an application! I will update my answer with another suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Download IE Drivers based on your OS (Windows 32 or 64 bit)

a. [Download](http://seleniumrelease.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip)
 Windows 32 bits driver

OR

b. [Download](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0.zip) Windows 64 bits driver

Extract the zip and copy IEDriverServer.exe file to some location e.g. E:\IEDriver

Write the following script

`from selenium import webdriver
 browser = webdriver.Ie("e:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")`

send values your inputs 'username' and 'password' and submit.

Run the script, it should open IE browser...